# Calling an instance method from a different class

Tags: java, class, object, methods, complex-numbers

The purpose of this program is to test another program I created.

It's called `ComplexNumber`. This class has everything from add, multiply, dividing complex numbers numbers and stuff and they are all in methods. The teacher wants us to create a testing class, here is what I have so far.

The problem I am having is calling the methods from the `ComplexNumber` class. For example: I tried calling the `plus` method, this method takes in two `ComplexNumber`s and adds them up. So far I've been testing these methods using the interaction panel and it has worked great. The way I called them in the interaction panel was by doing `first.plus(Second)` and this would give the final values.

On the testing class, I am having difficulty calling the methods.
I know that I need the class name.

I tried:

```
ComplexNumber.first.plus(second)
```

But it didn't work.
How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
class TestComplexNumber
{
    double real;         
    double imag;

    public TestComplexNumber(double a, double b)
    {
        this.real=a;
        if ((b<1000)&&(b>-1000))
            this.imag=b;
        else
        {
            this.imag=0;
            System.out.println("The value you typed in for imag is <1000 or >-1000, value of imag is assigned the value of 0.");
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        double real,imag;
        real=this.real;
        imag=this.imag;

        if (((real<0)||(real>0))&&(imag%1!=0))
        {
            if (roundThreeDecimals(imag)>0)
                return ""+roundThreeDecimals(real)+"+"+roundThreeDecimals(imag)+"i";
            else
                return ""+roundThreeDecimals(real)+""+roundThreeDecimals(imag)+"i";
        }
        else if ((real%1!=0)&&(imag!=0))
            return ""+roundThreeDecimals(real)+"+"+(int)imag+"i";
        else if((real==0)&&(imag%1!=0))
            return ""+imag+"i";        
        else if ((real==0)&&(imag !=0))
            return ""+(int)imag+"i";
        else if ((imag==0)&&(real!=0))
             return ""+(int)real+"";
        else if (((real<0)||(real>0))&&(imag<0))
            return ""+(int)real+"-"+(int)Math.abs(imag)+"i";
        else if((real!=0)&&(imag!=0))
            return ""+(int)real+"+"+(int)imag+"i";
        else 
            return "";
     }

     public static double roundThreeDecimals(double c)
     {
         double temp = c*1000;
         temp = Math.round(temp);
         temp = temp /1000;
         return temp;
     }  

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
        {
            //Testing decimal values
        TestComplexNumber first=new TestComplexNumber((int)(Math.random()*100)-(int)(Math.random()*100),(Math.random()*100));
            TestComplexNumber second=new      TestComplexNumber((Math.random()*100),(Math.random()*100)-(int)(Math.random()*100));
            //Testing whole values
            TestComplexNumber third=new TestComplexNumber((int)(Math.random()*100)-(int)(Math.random()*100),(int)(Math.random()*100));
            TestComplexNumber fourth=new TestComplexNumber((Math.random()*100)-(int)(Math.random()*100),(int)(Math.random()*100));

            System.out.println(first);
            System.out.println(second);
            System.out.println(third);
            System.out.println(fourth);      
            System.out.println("Test value for plus:"+first+second+" which added="+plus(second));  
        }

    }
}
```

Example of a method on the ComplexNumber class:

```
public ComplexNumber plus(ComplexNumber other) {
    ComplexNumber sum= new ComplexNumber(this.real,this.getImag());

    sum.real=(this.real)+(other.real);
    sum.setImag((this.getImag())+(other.getImag()));

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Post your `ComplexNumber` class. You need to create objects of `ComplexNumber` and then invoke methods on them

Comment: i have two objects:double real and double imag, i do not want to post my ComplexNumber class

Comment: `double real` and `double imag` are not objects. They are variables of type `double`. In your main method, you are creating objects of `TestComplexNumber` using the `new` keyword. You should do the same and create objects of `ComplexNumber` class and invoke its methods

Comment: My teacher said i have to create the testing program in a new class and not on the ComplexNumber class.

Comment: All i wanna is how do i call a instance method in a another class.

Comment: Create ComplexNumber objects in the main method of your Tester class. That solves all your problems. Can you please post your ComplexNumber class with just one method?

Comment: I put the plus method in from the ComplexNumber class

Comment: Can you show me what i have to do, i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // create two objects of ComplexNumbers with whatever values you like
        ComplexNumber numA = new ComplexNumber(....);
        ComplexNumber numB = new ComplexNumber(....);

        // then add them and store the returned reference into a new variable
        ComplexNumber result = numA.plus(numB);
        // print the number however you like
        System.out.println(result.real + " + i" + result.getImag());

    }

}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i have, you don't get it. i have to tell the computer which class to go into find the method you would do that by typing the class name and then the method and then the parameters:ComplexNumber.round(5.48)<The complexNuber is the class name and i am telling the computer to go into that class and find the method round and round the parameter. The problem i am having is to do the plus method i need to do first.plus(second)<this would work in the ComplexNumer class,if i were to do this in were clas i have to tell the computer to go the a class and i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you want to invoke the method like this: `ComplexNumber.first.plus(second)`? There are so many things incorrect with this

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: First, run the code that I have provided in my answer and tell me if you are getting the right result or not. Okay? Then post your entire ComplexNumber class. I suspect that the `round()` method in your class is a static method. Don't make things complicated than it already is. Remove the static declaration

Comment: Found the problem, you were right. the reason it wasn't working was because i put TestComplexNumber, it should of been ComplexNumber.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what this "interaction panel" is, but `first.plus(second)` from there should work no different than in the actual code.

`plus` is the method called in the `first` *instance*.

The method should not be `static`, as in `static ComplexNumber plus(ComplexNumber other)`, so you do not need the class name to use it.

In conclusion, to call an instance method from another class, you need an instance, which you have should have four calls to `new ComplexNumber()`, and **not** `new TestComplexNumber()`

---

> My teacher said i have to create the testing program in a new class and not on the ComplexNumber class

I think your real issue is that you have this class `TestComplexNumber`, which is only intended to be a "test class" (only need a `main` method), not a re-creation of the `ComplexNumber` class, which seems to be what you've done (since I see no plus, mutiply, divide, etc).

---

And if you are supposed to actually create a "test suite", not a `main` method, then you should use JUnit, or other testing framework